# how to do topic categorization for a string in python

Tags: python, nltk, labeling

I'm working at a project for which i need to categorize a text as a political news, news and current affairs

what libraries do you suggest to do so?

i did try doing a cathegorization with keywords, but i've been asked to use external libraries

Comment: This is an open ended question. You should check HuggingFace models section though. You could use out of the box classifiers or calculate sentence similarities between news articles and your labels and return the most similar label.